# Get previous n elements from list

Tags: c#

Given a collection, I want to iterate over each element and retrieve the previous N elements.

The data set is very small (hundred elements at most). Readability is primary concern.

Pseudo code...

```
var values = new List<decimal>
{
  1m,
  1.5m,
  2m,
  2.5m,
  3.0m,
  3.5m,
  4m,
  4.5m,
  5m
};

var previousElementsCount = 3;

for (var currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < values.Count - 1; currentIndex++)
{

  var range = values.GetPreviousElements(currentIndex, previousElementsCount);

  //currentIndex:0, result: []
  //currentIndex:1: result: [1]
  //currentIndex:2: result: [1.5, 1]
  //currentIndex:3: result: [2, 1.5, 1]
  //currentIndex:4: result: [2.5, 2, 1.5]
  //currentIndex:5: result: [3, 2.5, 2]
  // etc...
}

public static class ListExtensions 
{
  public static List<T> GetPreviousElements<T>(this List<T> list, int index, int previousElementsCount)
  {
    // ?
  }
}
```

How could you implement `GetPreviousElements`?

Thanks!

Comment: This really makes no sense

Comment: What is the problem here? You don't need a Queue. It looks like you've already solved this.

Comment: The current implementation of `List<T>` is backed by an array. If you are willing to take a dependency on an implementation detail, you could take advantage of that. Or, if the NPrevElements is for a constant N (per instance), then you ould build a simple `IList<T>` implementation with a list and a small fixed size collection that you rotate the last N elements through

Comment: @MarcoSalerno ok, what part doesn't make sense, what can I clarify? Simply saying this doesn't make sense, isn't helpful IMO...

Comment: @robbpriestley No, it isn't solved...there is no implementation of List GetRange which takes an index, an a count that returns the previous elements from the given index. I have updated example to hopefully disambiguate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like the below to get the previous elements (up to 3) and then reverse to meet your requirements. Not the most optimal solution, but works fine for a reasonably small `List<decimal>`:

```
var values = new List<decimal>
{
  1m,
  1.5m,
  2m,
  2.5m,
  3.0m,
  3.5m,
  4m,
  4.5m,
  5m
};

var previousElementsCount = 3;

for (var currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < values.Count; currentIndex++)
{
    var startIndex = (currentIndex > 0) ? (currentIndex - previousElementsCount >= 0) ? currentIndex - previousElementsCount : 0 : -1;
    var count = currentIndex - startIndex;

    var range = (startIndex >= 0) ? values.GetRange(startIndex, count).Reverse<decimal>() : new List<decimal>();
    Console.WriteLine($"currentIndex:{currentIndex}: result: [{string.Join(",", range.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())}]");            
}
```

Output:

```
currentIndex:0: result: []
currentIndex:1: result: [1]
currentIndex:2: result: [1.5,1]
currentIndex:3: result: [2,1.5,1]
currentIndex:4: result: [2.5,2,1.5]
currentIndex:5: result: [3.0,2.5,2]
currentIndex:6: result: [3.5,3.0,2.5]
currentIndex:7: result: [4,3.5,3.0]
currentIndex:8: result: [4.5,4,3.5]
```

**Edit:**
Here's another way of doing it where you use the previous index and walk back up to three elements to get the values:

```
var values = new List<decimal>
{
  1m,
  1.5m,
  2m,
  2.5m,
  3.0m,
  3.5m,
  4m,
  4.5m,
  5m
};

var previousElementsCount = 3;

for (var currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < values.Count; currentIndex++)
{
    var previousElements = new List<decimal>();

    if (currentIndex > 0)
    {
        var count = currentIndex - previousElementsCount < 0 ? 0 : currentIndex - previousElementsCount;

        for (var x = currentIndex - 1; x >= 0 && x >= count; x--)
        {
            previousElements.Add(values[x]);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"currentIndex:{currentIndex}: result: [{string.Join(",", previousElements.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())}]");            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for actually reading the question and providing an answer! :)

Comment: `var count = Math.Max(0, currentIndex - previousElementsCount);`

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yep, that simplifies the logic a little.

Comment: @user2966445 Do note, however, that `count` is a misleading variable name in this situation because it's not the count of the "used" elements.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed  Obviously there are many things that could be cleaned up about this code. I put it together in a few minutes to help the OP at least come up with a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take but basically the same idea:

```
var values = new List<decimal> { 1m, 1.5m, 2m, 2.5m, 3.0m, 3.5m, 4m, 4.5m, 5m };

var previousElementsCount = 3;

for (var currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < values.Count - 1; currentIndex++)
{
    int count = currentIndex >= previousElementsCount ? previousElementsCount : currentIndex;
    var range = values.GetRange(currentIndex - count, count);
    range.Reverse();
}
```